# How to disable default download or save option of a video file using html tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a list of video files and using anchor tag to display them. I want to play the videos without downloading or save button. I already disabled the right click option but still in some browsers the file will directly get downloaded on clicking the link. Can any one tell me how to avoid it? I have used the below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'> 
    // http://htmlgenerator.weebly.com 
    var tenth = ''; 

    function ninth() { 
        if (document.all) { 
            (tenth); 
            alert("Right Click Disable"); 
            return false; 
        } 
    } 

    function twelfth(e) { 
        if (document.layers || (document.getElementById && !document.all)) { 
            if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) { 
                (tenth); 
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if (document.layers) { 
        document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN); 
        document.onmousedown = twelfth; 
    } else { 
        document.onmouseup = twelfth; 
        document.oncontextmenu = ninth; 
    } 
    document.oncontextmenu = new Function('alert("Right Click Disable"); return false') 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h1>video</h1>
<a href="barsandtone.flv" target="_blank" >Video1</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you want to play it why don't you load video in any iframe or div???

Comment: Disabling the right click button is just annoying, But it's trivial to re-enable, just run : `document.oncontextmenu = true` in the console ;-)

Comment: @meena `alert("Right Click Disable")` really annoying, use `event.preventDefault()` instead. Plus, `new Function("...")` is bad, use `function (event){...}` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Use HTML5 Video tag.

Example (from W3schools):

`<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`.

Comment: this will directly play the video but i want to display the list of video first and on clicking the link the video has to play

Comment: @meena why don't you create your own list

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in the anchor tag.

e.g. `<a href="https://www.google.co.in/" class="anchorvid">Your Video</a>`

And add this javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('.anchorvid').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

This will stop anchor tags default behaviour.

Comment: do you have a live link or any working fiddle? Also try using `return false;` instead of `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: Did you use jQuery? Your fiddle did not include any jQuery. However I updated your fiddle and click event on anchor tag. Check it out and let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/n5yrE/4/